# Disable javascript inside embedded PDF displayed with Chrome PDF viewer

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, xss, pdf-viewer

PDF that contains javascript runs this code when embedded in html and displayed in Chrome. This is better described in this closed issue https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=511295

Is there any way how to disable the javascript support alltogether? Sadly i wan't even able to find what exactly is supported in chrome pdf viewer, only that this shouldn't lead to XSS. Still, randomly popping alerts are annoying even without immediate security threat.

Comment: I'm not sure if this really works, but it's my current solution:  install "uBlock Origin" extension » Enable "I am an advanced user" » Open a pdf file » Click on the extension and "disable javascript", then hit the padlock for "make it permanent".   It seems to be smart enough to apply this to all future pdf files.  However, I am not sure if the extension runs before Chrome's PDF viewer ... it it is later, then it would have been too late.  I'm too lazy to figure out how to generate a PDF with Javascript to test it out.

Comment: I'm surprised this isn't a more commonly talked about issue. I'm running into the same thing on one of my applications. Chrome seems to be the only browser that runs javascript inside a PDF, which seems really silly on Chrome's part.